# Passing smarty var to php

Tags: php, smarty

I have Smarty template file. $listing.activation_date is null when passing from Smarty to php. Any solution?

```
{$listing.activation_date}
{php}
$startDate = strtotime('now');

$interval = $startDate - strtotime($this->get_template_vars('$listing.activation_date'));
```

---

```
{$listing.activation_date} = 2012-Sep-05
```

I have changed $smarty to $this to prevent non-object error.

```
$this->assign("interval", $interval); 
$days = floor($this/ (60 * 60 * 24)); {/php} 
{if $days < 1} <img src=" {$GLOBALS.site_url}/templates/Natural/main/images/new.gif"/> 
{/if}
```

Is $days correct in {php} and then in Smarty $days<1?

Comment: Smarty is for representation. Do all your calculations in a 'regular' php script and pass the calculated values to Smarty. That is (in my opinion) the right way to use a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline PHP Smarty assign and wrap that variable into brackets:

```
{php}
    $startDate = strtotime('now');
    $interval = $startDate - strtotime('{$listing.activation_date}');
    $smarty->assign("interval", $interval);
{/php}
```

Comment: <!-- Start New  & Video Icon -->
{assign var="startDate" value = $smarty.now}
{assign var="endDate" value = $listing.activation_date|strtotime}
{math assign="diff" equation="(st - en)" st=$startDate en=$endDate }

{if $diff < 86400}
<img src="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/templates/Natural/main/images/new.gif"/>
{/if}

Answer (score 0):

In Smarty3 you do not need {php}:

```
{$interval = $smarty.now - {$listening.activation_date|strtotime}}
```

Since Smarty2 doesn't allow "complex" inline expression, you'd have to "dumb it down":

```
{assign var="now" value=$smarty.now}
{assign var="then" value=$listening.activation_date|strtotime}
{assign var="interval" value=$now-$then}
```

Whenever you find yourself using {php}, you're doing something "wrong". Smarty has a feature-rich plugin system that allows you to seperate logic from presentation